# Outlook export file — shut down Outlook account

Tags: email, outlook

My university deletes students' Outlook email account after they graduate and so I am exporting my inbox at a `.olm` file.

I figured this would be sufficient to save my meaningful emails that I want to save, but I wonder how I will ever open the `.olm` file if the account itself will be deleted...

Any ideas/info?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

*`OLM` files are used only by Mac as Database file by Microsoft Outlook and can't be opened by the Windows version of Outlook because the Windows version uses .PST files rather than the OLM format.*

*assuming you have mac if not then To open `OLM` files in Windows, you can first convert the `OLM` file to the PST.*

*But there are other ways to save Outlook emails*

1. Text only format
2. Outlook Message Format `.msg` – the older version of `.msg` 
   does not support the full range of Unicode characters.
3. Outlook Message Format – Unicode the newer of `.msg` that
   includes Unicode characters.

*I will use this `.msg` format.  These days ‘plain’ can have Unicode for emoji etc.*

4. Save to Word
5. Outlook Template .oft to make a template for new emails.
6. `HTML` – a web page version of the message
7. `MHT` – also a web page but with images etc embedded into a single
   file.

*making the subject line of the message the file name.*

*Remember all the above formats are indexed by OS, You will be able to find a saved message by searching words in the message.*

7. Save to PDF

*PDF is another way to store ‘permanent’ or archival documents.*

look into examples like python or VBA code that can help you save emails to the format you need.